# PLSQL Generate a string list separated by comma in a cursor

Tags: sql, string, plsql

**Here's my problem**: I'm working inside a pl/sql package where I have a loop that compares the rule with table of users. I need to build a comma separated list of strings (#1) in which I can obtain invalid users (users that doesn't match the rule) and then create a sql query (#2) to exclude them from the rule.

## 1 Comma separated list:

Z=table that results after comparing the rule with main table of users
 Below i am not sure if any of the two commented lines are good

```
declare user_list varchar2(4000)
IF Z IS NULL THEN
-- build the comma separated list
User_list:= --how to buil a list of strings?
END IF;
```

## 2 SQL statement:

--Using the created user_list, now just to exclude it from the main rule

```
IF USER_LIST IS NULL THEN 
'SELECT * FROM RULE WHERE USER NOT IN (:USER_LIST)'
ELSE
RETURN RESULT_FROM_RULE;
END IF;
```

Comment: Why can't you combine the two in a *SQL* statement using `NOT IN`

Comment: Also, is `IF USER_LIST IS NULL THEN` right?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement using dynamic sql. See below how you can do it. I have put the comments inline for understading the code.

```
create table table1 (id number,
                     ColumnName varchar2(100)) 

create table table2 (Id     number,   
                     col1  varchar2(100),
                     col2  varchar2(100),    
                     col3  varchar2(100));

 Insert all   
    into TABLE1 (ID, COLUMNNAME)  Values    (1, 'col1')
    into TABLE1 (ID, COLUMNNAME)  Values    (2, 'col2')
    into TABLE2 (ID, col1, col2, col3)  Values  (1, 'RRR', 'KKK', 'MMM')
    into TABLE2 (ID, col1, col2, col3)  Values  (2, 'ZZZ', 'PPP', 'QQQ')
    into TABLE2 (ID, col1, col2, col3)  Values  (3, 'LLL', 'NNN', 'DDD')
 select * from dual;
```

Code:

```
DECLARE
   var     VARCHAR2 (1000);
   v_sql   VARCHAR2 (2000);
   TYPE x_var IS TABLE OF table2%rowtype ;
   z_var   x_var;
   num number:=0;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (  SELECT  columnname
                   FROM table1
              )
   LOOP          
      num := num +1;      
      if num = 1 then
       var:= rec.columnname;       
       else
         var := var || ' , '|| rec.columnname;
      end if; 

   END LOOP;
   ---This is how the comma seperated list is generated. This answers your query `**1 Comma separated list:**`

   var := RTRIM (LTRIM (var, ','), ',');   

   --This is how you pass the string to your query . This answers your query `**2 SQL statement:**` 

   v_sql := 'select * from table2 where segment1 in ('|| var||')';    

   ---This is how you execute your query.

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql BULK COLLECT INTO z_var;

   --displaying the result of the query. If you are using a function you can return (z_var).
   FOR i IN 1 .. z_var.COUNT
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (z_var(i).Id  ||','||z_var(i).col1);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Output:

```
SQL> /       
1,RRR
2,ZZZ
3,LLL

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Note: Please note that the you can use a single query suggested by GurV and simplify your job as well.